# Modify a cleaning JSON object javascript function

Tags: javascript, json, data-cleaning

So, this is my function that deletes empty and null properties from a JSON object in Javascript. I need the function to delete also empty nested objects but its not doing it right now.  I have tried but failed several times to modify this function ( I got this from an old post in this site ).

Can someone help me with this?

#### Function

```
function clean_object(test, recurse) {
    for (var i in test) {
        if (test[i] === null || test[i] == ""  ) {
            delete test[i];
        } else if (recurse &&  typeof test[i] === 'object' ) {
            clean_object(test[i], recurse);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Object before cleaning

```
{ "data.openstack.public_ipv4": "falseip" }
```

#### Object after cleaning

```
{"data":{"openstack":{}}}
```

#### What I need

```
{}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: didn't check you function.. by the way you should compare for entry to be an object like `recurse &&  typeof test[i] ===  '[object Object]'`

Comment: @UsmanRana I tried that just now and it became even worse. It did not even delete the last level property like that.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: @Raedwald I already went through StackOverflow rules, and what I am asking falls into the category of "useful knowledge" and it would be "searched by someone else". Im not asking someone "please come and write this code for me". I cant find a solution for my problem, so I came to this site looking for help. If you dont know how to fix this ( as apparently you dont ) please restrain yourself from humiliating someone just because is "less knowledgeable" than you are.

Comment: IMHO, I don't understand the way to run this function. It needs to be detailed in the question. Can you add an example?

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez Basically im iterating through all properties of the object ( var i) and if they are null or empty im deleting that property. The thing is, I need to keep recursively iterating and also delete whatever is an "empty object". It seemed like a piece of cake at first, but I have been struggling with this all morning. I have tried to play around with the object length, and also tried to convert it to string and test it, but I have not been able to accomplish what I want. I dont have a lot of experience with Javascript or with JSON objects and that makes it even harder.

Comment: @MatiasBarrios I see... I'd like to know how can i execute this function to find a way to correct this code.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez You can define something like this : var myjson = { data:{ openstack :{ public_ipv4:""}}} and then just run clean_object(myjson); and then print myjson to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the first development step as provided as a partial approach I just wanted to make the example(s) work in a way that it clears all of an objects `null` values and zero-length string-values ...

```js
function clearEmptyValuesRecursively(obj) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    obj.forEach(function (item) {

      clearEmptyValuesRecursively(item);
    });
  } else {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
      var value = obj[key];

      if ((value === null) || (value === '')) {

        delete obj[key];

      } else if (typeof value !== 'string') {

        clearEmptyValuesRecursively(value);
      }
    });
  }
  return obj;
}


var data = {
  "data": {
    "openstack": {},
    "fullstack": "fullstack",
    "emptyString": ""
  },
  "emptyData": null
};

console.log('data - before : ', JSON.stringify(data));
clearEmptyValuesRecursively(data);
console.log('data - after : ', JSON.stringify(data));

data = {
  "data": {
    "openstack": {}
  }
};

console.log('data - before : ', JSON.stringify(data));
clearEmptyValuesRecursively(data);
console.log('data - after : ', JSON.stringify(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

... within the second step I kind of recycled the above approach. This time the recursively working function was build for mainly clearing empty main (data) structures like `{}` and `[]`, but it also takes care of deleting empty values as already shown with the first approach. Altogether this also is what the OP did ask for ...

```js
function clearEmptyStructuresRecursively(obj) {
  function isEmptyStructure(type) {
    return ((Object.keys(type).length === 0) || (Array.isArray(type) && (type.length === 0)));
  }
  function isEmptyValue(type) {
    return ((type == null) || (type === '')); // undefined or null or zero length string value.
  }
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    obj.forEach(function (item) {

      clearEmptyStructuresRecursively(item);
    });
  } else if (obj && (typeof obj !== 'string')) {

    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
      var value = obj[key];

      if (isEmptyValue(value) || isEmptyStructure(value)) {
        delete obj[key]; // ... delete ... and step into recursion ...

        clearEmptyStructuresRecursively(obj);
      }
      clearEmptyStructuresRecursively(value);
    });

    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
      var value = obj[key];

      if (isEmptyValue(value) || isEmptyStructure(value)) {
        delete obj[key]; // ... final delete.
      }
    });
  }
  return obj;
}

var data = {
  "data": {
    "openstack": {}
  }
};

console.log('data - before : ', JSON.stringify(data));
clearEmptyStructuresRecursively(data);
console.log('data - after : ', JSON.stringify(data));


data = {
  "data": {
    "openstack": {},
    "fullstack": "fullstack",
    "emptyString": ""
  },
  "emptyData": null
};

console.log('data - before : ', JSON.stringify(data));
clearEmptyStructuresRecursively(data);
console.log('data - after : ', JSON.stringify(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was trying to attempt!